# Safe coding practices in c : switching from dynamic to static memory allocation

Tags: c, heap-memory

I'm working on embedded systems and my goal is to improve the safety of an existing code. I'm trying to follow Nasa's rules : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Power_of_10:_Rules_for_Developing_Safety-Critical_Code

The existing code contains dynamically allocated instances and variables which is pretty common, I'm required to translate the program to static memory alocation.

**Is there generic practices and patterns to succesfully switch from dynamic to static memory allocation without breaking the code ?**

In particular, I'm having issues with those kinds of mallocs :

```c
unsigned short int * residuals = NULL;
residuals = (unsigned short int *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned short int)*input_params.x_size*input_params.y_size*input_params.z_size);

// in a other file 

block_samples[read_samples] = residuals[x + y*input_params.x_size + z*input_params.x_size*input_params.y_size]

// something else i have trouble with : double pointers 
predictor_params.weight_init_table = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *)*input_params.z_size);
```

I get segfaults when I try to statically allocates them with the following message in GDB :

`zero carry parity adjust sign trap INTERRUPT direction overflow RESUME virtualx86 identification`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by static allocation? Are you just declaring a structure at top level to go in a data segment? In this case you can't change the size of the allocation at all - it's fixed at compile time. Or are you doing a single malloc and then reusing that memory throughout? Again the size here is relatively fixed, unless you realloc when you need more space. (Is realloc allowed in your safety rules?)

Comment: It's obvious that if the max sizes are not known at compile time then this code is not safe. It should be refactored to use a fixed size buffer and calculate in multiple passes if it does not fit initially.  But also note that in embedded this might just overflow time instead of space.

Comment: i think the error of segmentation is linked to unsufficiant memory space when I allocate memory at declaration. It's more about safety than lack of memory space, as @Lundin is explaining bellow. I need to remove as much undeterministic elements as possible, and memory allocation by malloc is one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there generic practices and patterns to succesfully switch from dynamic to static memory allocation without breaking the code ?

No, not really. You'll have to rewrite all such code in pretty radical ways.

You have to realize *why* all safety-related and embedded systems ban `malloc`. The main reason is that it is non-deterministic. Instead of allowing completely variable sizes, you have to specify a maximum size for each such item, to cover the worst case scenario of the application.

Also, the presence of things like pointer-to-pointers instead of 2D arrays is a pretty certain indication that the original programmer didn't quite know what they were doing in the first place.

Additionally you need to drop the default types of C for `stdint.h` ones. That's standard practice in all embedded systems.

In general, I'd strongly advise to drop those "NASA rules" and implement MISRA-C instead. It's a *way* more professional and in-depth document. Some of the "NASA rules" simply don't make sense and the rest can be summarized as "No s***t Sherlock" beginner-level stuff which we were already told during our first beginner-level C programming class back in school. If these rules come as a surprise to someone, they shouldn't be writing mission-critical firmware in the first place.

Comment: thanks, I do understand more what my teacher wants me to do now ! Indeed the major issue is to have a deterministic allocation of memory and to cover the worse-case scenario. You mention that i needed to specifiy the size for each item, is there a c function to do so (allocate a given space in Bytes to an object) statically or you have to do it at declaration ?

Comment: @sytrics It has to be done at the point of declaration and the objects need to be large enough to sate the requirements of the product's specification.